# How to add html styling in html page in python

Tags: python, html

I am trying to style my HTML page created using Python, but somehow I am not getting it.

Following is my code without style tags

```
htmlfile = open(fruit+".html")
htmlfile.write("<html>\n")
htmlfile.write("<head>\n")
htmlfile.write("<title> homepage </title>\n")
htmlfile.write("</head>\n")
htmlfile.write("<body>\n")
htmlfile.write("<h1> <center> <b> {color:red;} Fruit-properties </b> </center> </h1>\n")
htmlfile.write("</body>\n")
```

anybody know how to add style tags in python?

Comment: ....consider using a proper templating engine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955615/python-template-engine

Comment: I thought about it. but html is very small portion of big code. so I am looking to add style tags in current code itself.

Comment: htmlfile.write("<h1> <center> <b>`<font color="red"> Fruit-properties </font>`</b> </center> </h1>\n")

Comment: thanks. it says invalid syntax at red word

Comment: That's because you need to escape the double quotes surrounding the word "red", otherwise Python will assume your HTML string ends right before that word. You could also use single quotes (i.e. `'`) or triple quotes for the actual python string. Check out the [docs on strings](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styling of HTML is done using [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS). First you need to learn CSS basics.

Then you can either provide a separate CSS style file or style HTML code inline:

```
  htmlfile.write("<h1 style='color: red; text-align: center'>Fruit-properties</h1>\n")
```